# Replacement of alert/prompt/confirm dialog boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I want to replace the default alert/prompt/confirm with my own and **do not want to use a plugin**. I did the styling but enable to figure out the action when the buttons are clicked (Ok/cancel/etc..). Here my code so far.

```
function jPromt(title,content,type,callback){
    var alert = $('.resources').find('.alert').clone(); //basic barebone
        alert.find('h3').html(title);
        alert.find('.content').prepend(content);

    var options = {
        "_prompt" : {"OK" :""},
        "_confirm": {"No" :"recomended", "Yes":""},
        "_input"  : {"Cancel":"recomended", "OK" :""}
    }

    for (var prop in obj) { // Create buttons
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { 
            var btn = "<button class='button_"+prop+" "+obj[prop]+"'>"+prop+"</button>";
            alert.find('.buttons').append(btn);

        }
    }

    $('.resource_loader').append(alert)
    $('body').append(alert).center().fadeIn('fast');

    // This is here I'm not realy sure what to do whit callbaks for each button.

    //if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {  
    //  callback();  
    //} 
}
```

I want it so that you can call jPromt() and the callback for each buttons will execute like so: or similar to it:

```
     ....

'ok', function(){
    //do stuff if ok was clicked
},
'cancel', function(){
    // canel was clicked, do stuff
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CezarisLT/u6AYe/5/

Thank you in advance. I will surely select your answer as correct.

Comment: The waiting in not a concern, its the handers that are created for the buttons $(..).click(... And in there is where everything is handled. Also this is sample code.

Comment: @Teemu Why do you think the OP wants it to be synchronous? The current code seems to expect it to be asynchronous.

Comment: Thank you @bfavaretto I was just about to say that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make that work with only a few modifications:

1. Pass an object as the `callback` parameter (I'd rename it to `callbacks`), where the keys represent the buttons, using the same format you defined for the options (`"Yes"`, `"No"` etc). your call should look like this:

   ```
   jPromt("test THE title","testing the contents","_confirm", {
       'No' : function(){
           alert("testing NO");
       },
       'Yes' : function(){
           alert("testing YES");
       }
   });
   ```
2. Make `btn` a jQuery object inside your loop over `obj`, so you can attach a handler
3. Check if the `callbacks` parameter has a handler for the current `prop`; if yes, attach to `btn`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/u6AYe/7/

Comment: Your a wizard or something? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is...

1. give your buttons actual click handlers invoking the callback
2. in your callback you inspect which button was actually clicked

Something like...

```
function jPromt(title,content,type,callback){
    var myAlert = $('.resources').find('.alert').clone(); //basic barebone
        myAlert.find('h3').html(title);
        myAlert.find('.content').prepend(content);

    var options = {
        "_prompt" : {"OK" :""},
        "_confirm": {"No" :"recomended", "Yes":""},
        "_input"  : {"Cancel":"recomended", "OK" :""}
    };

    if( options.hasOwnProperty(type) ){
        obj = options[type];
    }

    for (var prop in obj) { // Create buttons
        var $btn = $("<button class='button_"+prop+" "+obj[prop]+"'>"+prop+"</button>");
        $btn.attr('btn-type',prop.toUpperCase());
        myAlert.find('.buttons').append($btn);
        $btn.click(callback);
    }

    $('body').append(myAlert.show());
}

jPromt("test THE title","testing the contents","_confirm",
    function(){
        answer = $(this).attr('btn-type');
        if(answer == 'YES'){
            alert("Yes!");
        }else{
            alert("No!");
        }
    }
);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/u6AYe/8/ ...